# How to obtain this matrix by reordering the basis vectors?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, bilinear-form

I have a bilinear form $\phi$ and a basis $\{e_1,e_2,\dots, e_n\}.$ Using this I construct a matrix $A$ such that $A_{i,j} = \phi(e_i,e_j)$  for $1\leq i,j\leq n.$

This gives me a matrix that looks like this:

$$A = \left(\begin{array}{cccccc}
\left[\begin{array}{cc}
0 & 1\\
-1 & 0
\end{array}\right] &  &  &  &  & 0\\
 & \ddots\\
 &  & \left[\begin{array}{cc}
0 & 1\\
-1 & 0
\end{array}\right]\\
 &  &  & 0\\
 &  &  &  & \ddots\\
0 &  &  &  &  & 0
\end{array}\right).$$

I want to show that if we reorder the basis then we can get,
$$B =\begin{bmatrix}
    0       & -I_k  & 0 \\
    I_k       & 0   & 0 \\
    0  & 0 & 0 
\end{bmatrix}.$$

Here $I$ is the identity matrix. I tried a bunch of examples, but I could not see any special pattern. Any ideas will be much appreciated.

Comment: The diagonal dots represent `0` terms?

Comment: In the matrix $A$ the dots on the diagonal represent the same block being continued $k$ times.

Comment: Even in the lower part of the diagonal?

Comment: No, not in the lower part. That will be all zeros.

Answer (score 2):

Notations:
Rewrite your basis as:
$(f_1,f_{-1},f_2,f_{-2},\ldots,f_k,f_{-k},g_1,\ldots,g_s)$. Under this basis you obtain the matrix $A$.
Now reorder the basis as:
$(f_{-1},f_{-2},\ldots,f_{-k},f_1,f_2,\ldots,f_k,g_1,\ldots,g_s)$, you will get $B$.

Comment: Could you give some justification, if possible?

Comment: This puts $I_k$ on the top right and $-I_k$ on the bottom left. I want the reverse form?